# Clojurescript: how to make a web app version coexist with desktop electron version

Tags: electron, clojurescript, reagent, re-frame

I have created a leiningen-based clojurescript webapp.

More specifically, I am using the re-frame template: https://github.com/Day8/re-frame-template.

I wonder if it is possible to compile this project into an electron-based desktop app? I noticed there are electron templates like https://github.com/Gonzih/cljs-electron, but I have no idea how to make the web version coexist with the electron version.

Is this even possible?

Update:

To make my question more clear:

How do you make the electron-based version and web-based version share the same code base? Is there any examples for doing so?

Answer (score 1):

I've shipped re-frame apps that run in Electron, so this is certainly possible. We host our JS on the web, so we could serve our apps as webapps, we just choose not to. I didn't work on the Electron setup, but any ClojureScript/Electron template should get you started.

Your question about web versions coexisting with Electron isn't very clear. You can either serve your app from the web and treat Electron as a browser, or you could ship compiled ClojureScript and run it locally.